# How Google can check whether an application is installed from Play Store or Not?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

If a developer turns ON Google Play's [Anti Piracy Setup](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/antipiracy), the application cannot access the play services if it is not installed from Play Store(so says Google). My question is how Google verifies this? More than that I need to know, if I can install an application from the play store, then modify the apk and then re-installs it in my phone manually(by enabling 'install from unknown sources') AND then use the play services?

Comment: No, you can't do that. The phone keeps track of which app (`com.android.vending`, etc.) was used to install the app, and reinstalling or updating an app is considered installation too.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but normally which application does that installation if I open the apk from my File Manager app?

Comment: Can I trick the phone into thinking that the application was indeed installed from Play Store?

Comment: Also, please post your first comment as answer, so I can accept that :)